iOS/Flutter open app from Instagram deep link not working
In my Flutter app, I setup Universal Links with app_links so when users are tapping on a defined link, it will open the app, if downloaded. These are my associated domains:

An example URL that people should be able to add in Instagram is:

https://wishlist-88d58.web.app/cvV6APQAt4XQY6xQFE6rT7IUpA93/dISu32evRaUHlyYqVkq3/c6fdfaee-085f-46c0-849d-aa4463588d96

And my .well-known/apple-app-site-association looks like:
{
  "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
      {
        "appID": "SN26HDFT24.com.ckbusiness.Wishlists",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}

That is working perfectly fine.
BUT: User are also posting the URL e.g. in Instagram-Stories, and the the weird thing is, that when tapping on the URL inside a Instagram-Story, the app will not be opened, but instead the In-App-Browser of Instagram.
Why does Instagram not open my app directly? There must be a way to open an App thought Instagram right?
Let me know if you need any more information.
UPDATE:
So apparently urlgenius found a way to get it done (found this video). If they can do it, we as developers should be able to do it as well right? :D

It's a bug in the Meta - https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/470205278761649/
